# Muestra id y no el valor de name que tiene en tabla, laravel 5.5

Tags: php, html5, laravel, crud

Buenas, tengo una tabla llamada departaments (id, name) y una tabla llamada users (id, name, departament_id) que tienen una relación de uno a muchos (La clave foránea esta en user), es decir, un departamento tiene muchos usuarios. Cuando un usuario se crea se guarda el id pero cuando quiero mostrarlo en el listado se muestra solo el id en lugar del name al que pertenece el id que se guardo de la tabla departaments.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Adjunto el codigo del listado

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="background-color: white;">
<thead> 
        <tr>
            <th width="20px">ID</th>
            <th>CODIGO USUARIO</th>
            <th>NOMBRE</th>
            <th>APELLIDO</th>
            <th>DEPARTAMENTO</th>
            <th>CORREO</th>
            <th>TELEFONO</th>
            <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>             
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $user->id}}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->user_code }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->departament_id}}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->mail}}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->phone}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('users.show',$user->id) }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in btn btn-primary btn-sm"> Ver</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('users.edit',$user->id) }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn btn-warning btn-sm"> Editar</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <form action="{{ route('users.destroy',$user->id) }}" method="POST">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                        <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn btn-danger btn-sm"> Eliminar</button>
                    </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit1:** La creación y el editado de usuarios se hace perfectamente, solo que necesito mostrar el valor en lugar del id de departaments, el name.
Este es el codigo del controlador de users

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Departament;
use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;

class UserController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    $users = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate();
    return view('users.index', compact('users'));
}

  Public function create()
{
    $departaments = departament::all();
    return view('users.create', compact('departaments'));
}

public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    $user = new user;

    $user->user_code = $request->user_code;
    $user->name      = $request->name;
    $user->lastName  = $request->lastName;
    $user->mail      = $request->mail;
    $user->phone     = $request->phone;
    $user-> status = 1;
    $user-> created_usr = $request->created_usr;
    $user-> updated_usr = $request->updated_usr;
    $user-> status_log = $request->status_log;
    $user-> departament_id = $request->departament_id;

    $user->save();  

    return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('info','El usuario '.$user->name.' fue creado exitosamente');
}

 Public function edit($id)
{
    $departaments = departament::all();
    $user = User::find($id);
    return view('users.edit', compact('user'), compact('departaments'));
} 

 public function update(UserRequest $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    $user->user_code = $request->user_code;
    $user->name     = $request->name;
    $user->lastName = $request->lastName;
    $user->mail     = $request->mail;
    $user->phone    = $request->phone;
    $user-> departament_id = $request->departament_id;

    $user->save();  

    return redirect()->route('users.index')
                     ->with('info','El usuario ha sido actualizado');
}

Public function show($id) 
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    return view('users.show', compact('user'));
}

 Public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->delete();

    return back()->with('info','El usuario fue eliminado');
}
}
```

**Edit2:** Agrego el modelo de departaments que es el unico que tiene una relacion (Un departamento a muchos usuarios)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Departament extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
];

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
}
```

Comment: Si es una relación uno a muchos desde Despartamento el hasMany debe de estar en el modelo Departamento y el belongsTo en Users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es sencillo , le hace falta la relación [belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) uno a muchos inverso , para poder obtener el departamento de un Usuario. Tal y como están sus relaciones solo podrá obtener los usuarios que pertenecen a un departamento.

Esta relación acepta como segundo valor el nombre del campo de la clave foránea 
que debería pasar también.

En su Modelo `User` agregue la relación

```
public function departamento()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Departament','departament_id');
}
```

Y desde la Vista

```
<td>{{ $user->departamento->name }}</td>
```

Comment: Obtengo el siguiente error:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: ¿A que se puede deber ese error?

Comment: @Kinafune básicamente que no está retornando una instancia de la clase Departament , en su lugar solo regresa el id . ¿Funcionó ?

Comment: Pude solucionarlo agregando en el index $user->departamento['name'] en lugar $user->departamento->name y conservando el segundo parámetro.
@Dev. Joel Gracias por su paciencia y ayuda.

Comment: @Kinafune interesante , reproducí su error y funciona correctamente. algo se me está escapando quizá. Me alegra que haya ayudado aunque sea un poco. :) , Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa, utilizando Query Builder, puede ser la siguiente:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    $users = User::join('departaments', 'departaments.id', '=', 'users.departament_id')
    ->select('users.*', 'departaments.name as departament_name')
    ->orderBy('users.id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate();

    return view('users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

Y luego, en el listado, simplemente reemplazas por lo siguiente:

```
<td>{{ $user->departament_name}}</td>
```

Saludos